# Viewing gifs multiple times - using bandwidth each time?

Tags: caching, gif, bandwidth

I have a webpage that has a large list of gifs on it. If I navigate to the page frequently throughout the day, will I be using a lot of bandwidth to load all of the gifs, or do the images get cached somewhere? Is there a way to reduce the bandwidth I use if I know I will be navigating to this page frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the normal cases the browser will cache your images. By most of the normal I mean that the server is configured to add [expires headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). If you are using apache - you can look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) how to do this. Another way of doing, but worse it to do this through the application. Also I assume here that the browser is not told explicitly not to cache something you can do this by prepending ?random_stuff to your image src in the end.

To check if the images you are currently viewing are taken from cache - check your response status. For example in chrome inspector if you see 304 this means that it was taken from the cache. [image]

Comment: Cool. I just checked and they are all status 200, but the size field indicates: "cache" so I'm guessing I'm alright?